# AWS CloudTrail and S3 bucket region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created cloudtrail in us-east-1 region but i have given s3 bucket which is of south-ap-1 region. Will this create a problem for cloudtrail to put logs in bucket which is in different region? Currently i am facing such issue.

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: Does the bucket work for a CloudTrail in the _same_ region?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Receiving CloudTrail Log Files from Multiple Regions - AWS CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/receive-cloudtrail-log-files-from-multiple-regions.html):

> You can configure CloudTrail to deliver log files from multiple regions to a single S3 bucket for a single account. For example, you have a trail in the US West (Oregon) Region that is configured to deliver log files to a S3 bucket, and a CloudWatch Logs log group. When you apply the trail to all regions, CloudTrail creates a new trail in all other regions. This trail has the original trail configuration. CloudTrail delivers log files to the same S3 bucket and CloudWatch Logs log group.

This is a little different to creating each trail separately.